# Pandas invalid type comparison error

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

For some reason, which I can't find in the Pandas changelog for 0.17.1, comparing a datetime series with an int value (Unix epoch) does not work anymore. Could anyone please explain this or point me to the right section in the changelog?

Working in 0.16.2

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime
>>> d = pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)])
>>> d
0   2016-01-01
1   2016-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> d.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
>>> d > 10
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Error in 0.17.1

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime
>>> d = pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)])
>>> d > 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sven/tmp/pandastest/pandas-0.17.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 726, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "/Users/sven/tmp/pandastest/pandas-0.17.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 657, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: What is your numpy version, I get a similar error on pandas `0.17.1` numpy `1.9.3`: 

`C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
    655             # integer comparisons
    656             if is_datetimelike_v_numeric(x, y):
--> 657                 raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
    658 
    659             # numpy does not like comparisons vs None`

Comment: `np.__version__: '1.10.4'` (for both)

Comment: it maybe worth checking on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) about this, it may be a regression

Comment: Couldn't find anything related on Github unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use an explicit conversion:

```
u_time_ns = d.apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime64().view('int64'))
u_time_ns

0    1451606400000000000
1    1451606400000000000
dtype: int64

u_time_ns > 10

0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Or, if you want to rely on pandas timestamps being stored as `datetime64[ns]`:

```
u_time_ns = d.view('int64')
```

Sorry, no idea why this changed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use this as a workaround for the time being.